# Windows 11, How to have 2 outputs with 1 command?

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, windows-11

Windows 11 command prompt:
Output1:
This command `chkdsk /r d:` works fine and
outputs data to screen.

But how much time does above command take?
ran second command and Answer was
`6 hour 12 minutes ...` for a usb disk

.
.

Output2:
Win11 command prompt:

`powershell -Command "Measure-Command { chkdsk /r d: }"`

```
Days              : 0
Hours             : 6
Minutes           : 12
Seconds           : 45
Milliseconds      : 703
Ticks             : 223657036568
TotalDays         : 0.258862310842593
TotalHours        : 6.21269546022222
TotalMinutes      : 372.761727613333
TotalSeconds      : 22365.7036568
TotalMilliseconds : 22365703.6568
```

Problem is 2 outputs required 2 commands.
Question is:  How to get both outputs to screen with one command?

1. chkdsk output
2. time output

--

Comment: Write a batch script that launches the two ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a pipe to `Out-Default` to force display of the `Measure-Command` expression output:

```sh
# only outputs the time:
Measure-Command {ping localhost}

# Using Out-Default shows ping results and time:
Measure-Command {ping localhost | Out-Default}
```

Writing text to the console may affect the execution speed of a command, so output is suppressed by default.

---

For programs like `chkdsk` that display to the console directly (instead of using stdout), you can still use a standard timer like:

```
$sw = [Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()
chkdsk /r d:
$sw.Stop()
$sw.Elapsed  ## display timer
```

---

or to do this all from command prompt:

```
powershell -c $sw = [Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew();chkdsk /r d: ;$sw.Stop();$sw.Elapsed
```

Comment: Cpt.Whale posted a 47 character command:  
```Measure-Command {ping localhost | Out-Default}``` 
and a 69 character command was used: 
```powershell -Command "Measure-Command { chkdsk /r d: | Out-Default }"``` 
Above 69 character command gave two (2) unexpected results:  
1. many lines of progress like:  
```Progress: 244095320 of 244142544 done; Stage: 99%; Total: 99%; ETA:   0:00:03 .```  
and ...

Comment: Above 69 character command gave two (2) unexpected results:  
2. Limited chkdsk output, meaning 
```No Stage 1:``` Examining basic file system structure ... 
```No Stage 2:``` Examining file name linkage ... 
```No Stage 3:``` Examining security descriptors ... 
```No Stage 4:``` Looking for bad clusters in user file data ... 
```No Stage 5:``` Looking for bad, free clusters ...  

Just ```12``` Lines like:  
```976700872 KB total disk space.``` etc..  
Question:  What is the one (1) command to have a 
normal ```chkdsk``` output and duration time?

Comment: @joseph22 I've added an example using a `[Stopwatch]` timer which does not affect output/display

Comment: Update ```sw.Stop()``` 'sw.Stop' is   
not recognized as an   
internal or   
external command, operable program or   
batch file.

Comment: @joseph22 did you forget the `$`?

Comment: With Windows 11, administrator command prompt, 2 attempts were done: 
1. copied and pasted with $ ```$sw = [Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()``` C:\Windows\System32>$sw = [Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()
'$sw' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. __ 
2. copied and pasted without $ ```sw = [Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()``` C:\Windows\System32>sw = [Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()
'sw' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: @joseph22 it looks like you were using command prompt instead of powershell? I've added an example for launching it from cmd instead

Comment: At command prompt, similar times, ```5 hours 22 minutes``` ...
```TotalSeconds      : 19391.4329211``` to run cmd 
```powershell -c $sw = [Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew();chkdsk D: /f /r /x          ;$sw.Stop();$sw.Elapsed ``` versus 
```powershell -c $sw = [Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew();chkdsk D: /R /scan /perf /X ;$sw.Stop();$sw.Elapsed ``` timed at 
```TotalSeconds      : 19368.1064841``` differs by 23.326437 Seconds ```chkdsk D: /R /scan /perf /X``` was faster by ```0.12%``` or 0.12 Percent faster.

Comment: If that command allowed you to get both outputs, consider marking this as the answer? Thanks!